# Изменение существующей строки

Tags: c++, строки

Здравствуйте. Мне хотелось бы понять, как можно реализовать изменение строки, введенной прежде с помощью функции getline в консольном приложении.

Например:

```
string Input;
cout << "Введите строку: ";
getline(cin, Input);
cout << "Изменить строку: ";
```

А далее поместить строку из Input в консоль, при этом, что бы можно было бегать курсором по строке и менять нужные нам символы на другие, а затем сохранить эту строку в новом виде.

Comment: Это не С++ strings, но если подходить серьезно, то посмотрите на [The GNU Readline Library](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). Именно ее используют большинство утилит (в т.ч. bash)

Comment: @avp Спасибо, попробую разобраться, как новичок, с этой библиотекой

Comment: @avp, ссылка не рабочая. Я нашёл такую: https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> //решение не кроссплатформенное, работает только на Windows
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
  COORD coord;
  string Input;
  cout << "Введите строку: ";
  getline(cin, Input);
  cout << "Изменить строку: " << "\n";
  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO bi;
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &bi); //записываем информацию о буфере экрана в консоли в bi
  coord.X = bi.dwCursorPosition.X; //получаем координаты курсора (это будут координаты начала строки после ее вывода)
  coord.Y = bi.dwCursorPosition.Y;
  cout << Input;
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord); //устанавливаем курсор на ранее полученные координаты
  getline(cin, Input);
  cout << Input;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, но как изменить код, что бы новые символы не перезаписывали старые, будто пользуешься "Insert" при вводе текста, а добавлялись между символами?
Как найти эту координату между символами